How can a polynomial function of degree k equal to it's interpolation of degree n (when n is greater than k)
Let $f∈Π_k$ (the set of all the polynomials of the degree of $k$ at last) and $x_0,x_1,…,x_n$ be the node points such that $k≤n$. Show that
$$P_n (x)=f(x)$$
Where $P_n$ is the interpolation function of $f$.

We want to show $$f(x)=P_n(x)$$ or in other words $$E(x)=0$$
we know $$E(x)=(x-x_0)(x-x_1)...(x-x_n)f[x_0, x_1, ..., x_n, x]\>,x\in I[x_0, x_1, ..., x_n]$$
and also $$f[x_0, x_1, ..., x_n, x]=\frac{{f}^{n+1}(\theta_n)}{(n+1)!}$$
where $\theta_n\in I[x_0, x_1, ..., x_n]$.
in other hand we know $f\in \Pi_k$ and $k\leq n$ thus $${f}^{n+1}(x)=0$$ and at least $E(x)=0$, hence the judgment is fixed.
